# Is it possible to get the uid of the current process owner?

Tags: crystal-lang

In Crystal, I am comparing certain files. I want to see if the `file.a` has the same owner as `file.b`. I thought I would use `File.info("file.a").owner`. However, I haven't found a way to get the uid of the user of the current process, other than starting another process:

```
`id -u #{`whoami`.strip}`
```

Is there a native way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, an API method to access the process' current user is missing. But there is an [open PR](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/5627) on the Github repository which declares a `Process.user` method.

For now, you can either shell out as demonstrated in the question or apply the patch from the mentioned PR to your source code. And hopefully it will be included in the next Crystal release.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly look at [the official api](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.0/File/Info.html#owner%3AUInt32-instance-method) but only since 0.25.0.
I think that you must update crystal to 0.25.0

Comment: The question is about the user of the current process, not the owner of a file (although that's also mentioned).